# Submenu of a menu doesn't open

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ngx-bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

   <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown mr-2 cursor-pointer" dropdown>
     <a class="btn nav-link dropdown-toggle" dropdownToggle>

     </a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" *dropdownMenu>
      <a class="btn dropdown-item" *ngFor="let language of languages" (click)="setLanguage(language)">

       <span style="vertical-align: super;"></span>
      </a>
     </div>
    </li>

    <!-- utente con avatar -->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown mr-2 cursor-pointer" dropdown>
     <a class="btn nav-link float-right mt-1 pr-4" dropdownToggle>
      <span class="float-left mt-1">
          <i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size: 1.5rem;"></i>
          <!-- prevedere user image -->
        </span>
      <span class="float-right mt-1 ml-1">
          <div><b>user</b></div>
          <div *ngIf="currentUser.roles && currentUser.roles.length == 1">desc</div>
          <div *ngIf="currentUser.roles && currentUser.roles.length > 1">role</div>
        </span>
     </a>
     <!-- menu -->
     <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" *dropdownMenu>
      <!-- logo confidi -->
    <div class="dropdown-item text-center user-image">
     <img [src]="userService.getUserPicture(currentUser?.image?.content)" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
     <!-- ultimo accesso -->
    <div class="dropdown-item">
     <div class="font-weight-bold">access </div>
     <div>date</div>
    </div>
    <!-- matricola -->
    <div class="dropdown-item">
     <div class="font-weight-bold">numer </div>
     <div>user</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ruoli -->
    <div class="nav-item dropdown mr-2 cursor-pointer" dropdown>
     <a class="btn nav-link dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" dropdownToggle>roles</a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" *dropdownMenu>
      <a class="btn dropdown-item" *ngFor="let role of currentUser.roles; let i = index">
       code - desc
      </a>
     </div>
    </div>


    <a class="dropdown-item logout-link" (click)="logout()">
     <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> <span class="font-weight-bold">logout</span></a>
  </div>
  </li>


  </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
</header>
```

I have a dropdown-menu that contains multiple dropdown-item and an item that I want to be a submenu(that contains a list of item).
I add the submenu on my menu but when I try to open it does not open.

Here is the stackblitz

https://angular6-bootstrap4-navbar-j8ar1z.stackblitz.io

As you see there is a submenu called **roles** that doesn't open. How can I fix it?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Your example does not work. currentUser is not defined.

Comment: it's strange.. I edited the question adding the code. Can you check it

Comment: check now if works, perhpaps I also added the code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your HTML - you cannot nest `<li>` tag inside of another `<li>` tag.

> The **HTML `<li>` element** is used to represent an item in a list. It must be contained in a parent element: an ordered list (`<ol>`), an unordered list (`<ul>`), or a menu (`<menu>`).

Source: [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

You can put `<ul>` inside of `<li>` though. It is actually a proper way to create a nested list.

Another thing is that you are trying to use nested dropdown and these seem to still be [an experimental feature of ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns)

Basic working example:

```
 <!-- template.html !-->
<ul >
  <li dropdown  [autoClose]="false" container="body">
       <a dropdownToggle class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
         (click)="false">Languages <span class="caret"></span></a>

  <ul id="dropdown-nested" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu"
      role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-nested">
    <li role="menuitem" *ngFor="let lang of languages"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">{{lang}}</a></li>


  </ul>
  </li>

  <li dropdown  [autoClose]="false" container="body">
       <a dropdownToggle class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
         (click)="false">User <span class="caret"></span></a>

  <ul id="dropdown-nested" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu"
      role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-nested">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">Settings</a></li>

    <li role="menuitem" dropdown triggers="mouseover" placement="right" container="body">
      <a dropdownToggle class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle"
         (click)="false">Roles<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li role="menuitem" *ngFor="let role of currentUser.roles"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">{{role}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

      <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
// Component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      public menu: {}[] = [];
      languages =  ['pl', 'en', 'de', 'es'];
      currentUser = {roles: ['admin', 'inboxUser', 'developer']}
    }
```

[Example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cq5tp6)

Comment: so as you can see I added a snippet and change the <li> in <div> but the problem still remains

Comment: Angular directives are still not nested properly. You need to follow an example from ngx-bootstrap documentation.

Comment: I follow an example.. infact the main menu work, but just in this case it doesn't work

Comment: so i follow you example and I seen it works.. the only thing that not works is the placement="left". I have the menu at right and when I hover I wanna open the submenu on left. But it continues to open or bottom or in right

Comment: I see that also in you example if I change the placement right with left doesn't work

Comment: also if i add .dropleft attribute it opens on bottom and no on left

Comment: and a important thing I see.. if I remove [autoClose]="false" and try to click on one item on submenu it closes automatically. there is any way to fix it?. because i dont need the mousehover, I open the submenu with click. but if I click it closes

Comment: [insideClick]="true" is the response ;) thank you for the answer